# Restrict number of Listeners in JMS Queues

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, spring-jms

I was just looking at JMS and activeMq documentation to see if we can restrict the number of consumers that can subscribe to a given queue. I see the options for concurrent consumers that can receive messages but NOT for all consumers. Do you know of any such property where we can say in one specific queue, only 2 listeners at a max can register. The 3rd listener registering should get an error response and can retry to see if a slot is available after 1 hour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your own Broker Plugins and attempt to implement what you want.  There is no option to do this by default on the Broker, and the retry logic would need to be something you implement on the client side as well.